# Move text out of image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make this structure with bootstrap:
[image]

So, in desktop, it shows like the image, and on tablet/mobile it shows the image first and below the text, for making it responsive. Live example [here](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html).

```
 <div class="container" style="height: 100%;margin-top: 200px;">
  <div class="row">

      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 100px;">
    <div class="img-container col-lg-7 mx-auto">
      <img class="lozad" alt="" src="img/_MG_6501%20copia.jpg" data-src="img/_MG_6501%20copia.jpg" width="100%" />
          </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 mx-auto home-text-div">
             <h1>ESTA ES MI SEGUNDA CASA"</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Updated with the code and the live example, but I can't get to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position relative /absolute to implement

```css
.banner{
position: relative;
}

.banner h1{
position: absolute;
      position: absolute;
    color: violet;
    right: -70px;
    bottom: -50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .banner h1{
  position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 banner">
   <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/160699/girl-dandelion-yellow-flowers-160699.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beautiful-beauty-dandelion-160699.jpg&fm=jpg" class="img-thumbnail" />
      <h1>Your text show here</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need that the middle part of the text goes out the image, only a bit out like the image.

Comment: updated, you can set position right to negative number

Comment: in your live sample, they also use position relative and absolute like my demo

Answer (score 0):

Add This Way

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-1">
                <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  }

span {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width:991px) {
  span {
    width: 50%;
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h91p2v3q/2/